# unable to instantiate object of a model in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

I have created a `schema` and `model` in `q.js`.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const qSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    a1: String,
    a2: [String]
});

module.export = mongoose.model("Q", qSchema);
```

In `app.js`, I have imported `q.js` and am trying to instantiate an object of type `Q` but I get error `Q is not defined` UPDATE - the error changed to `TypeError: Q is not a constructor`

app.js

```
const q = require('./schema/q');

async function addQ(){
  const q = new Q({
    d: "d1",
    h: ["h1", "h2"]
  });
  console.log(`q object : ${JSON.stringify(question)}`);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE - If I move the code to `app.js` then things work. It seems I am not exporting `Q` correctly. If I print `Q` (output of `mongoose.model("Question", questionSchema);`), I get

```
function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
      model.hooks.execPreSync('createModel', doc);
      if (!(this instanceof model)) {
        return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
      }
      const discriminatorKey = model.schema.options.discriminatorKey;

      if (model.discriminators == null || doc == null || doc[discriminatorKey] == null) {
        Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
        return;
      }

      // If discriminator key is set, use the discriminator instead (gh-7586)
      const Discriminator = model.discriminators[doc[discriminatorKey]] ||
        getDiscriminatorByValue(model.discriminators, doc[discriminatorKey]);
      if (Discriminator != null) {
        return new Discriminator(doc, fields, skipId);
      }

      // Otherwise, just use the top-level model
      Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
    }
```

Comment: q !== Q maybe because of this?

Comment: I am exporting `Q` in `q.js` which should be available in `q` in `app.js`.

Comment: UPDATE - the error changed to `TypeError: Q is not a constructor`.

Comment: Can you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example? There is no `Q` imported in `app.js`

Comment: Please double check your exports (q.js > module.exports = mongoose.model('Q', qSchema) ; app.js > const Q = require('./schema/q');